# Texture paint is purple

Tags: texture-painting

I tried to paint but my cube is fully purple no matter what color I choose.

What should I doo to fix this ?

[image]

Comment: Purple in Blender usually means something is missing. An image, a broken link...

Comment: maybe you've disconnected the Image Texture? maybe show your node setting or share your file

Comment: You haven't saved your image.  It still has a star next to it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe haven't applied any texture to your model... Purple skin usually mean no texture, so you can't paint over it... but you can apply material on it... and for that to show you will need to go to the Dev or Render tab

Comment: I don't understand. Tried it in shader mode but the same.

Answer (score 1):

You have no 'selected' texture in your material !

The 3D viewport uses the material to decide the texture to display and paint to, not the Image Editor.